# How to separate the errors in expressjs

Tags: html, express

I am trying to separate the errors instead of it having return all of them in one spot. How do i inject them separately?

```
/Handle the post data
router.post("/registration",(req,res)=>{
const errorMessages = [];  
//fields value holder
var form= 
{
nameholder : req.body.yourName,
emailholder : req.body.email
};

    //validation for null ptr
    if(req.body.yourName=="")
    {  // document.getElementById('name_val').innerHTML="You must enter your name";
            errorMessages.push("You must enter your name");
    }
    // validation for null ptr
    if(req.body.email=="")
    {
       // document.getElementById('pass_val').innerHTML="You must enter an email.";
        errorMessages.push ("You must enter an email.");
    }
```

To display the errors:

```
{{#each errors}}
<div >{{this}} </div>
{{/each}}
```

my Output:
Goal: is to have each error appear at the bottom of their respective textbox

[image]

Comment: Do you want to validate input data? If so, I suggest to check this - https://github.com/hapijs/joi

Comment: @ViktorGusev , sorry that wasnt my intention. I added a picture to show what i meant, hope that helps so that you can help me.